# Angular - Page not found is not getting executed while accessing URL directly

Tags: angular

Following is my route

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', component: Layout, 
    children: [
      { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent},
      {
        path: 'Product', component: ProductComponent},
        children: [
          { path: '', component: ProducListComponent},
          { path: 'add', component: ProductAddComponent },
        ]
      },
    ],
  },
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent },
];
```

This is working as expected.

When i access url directly, i am facing some weird behaviour

http://localhost:4200/home -- Working

http://localhost:4200/Product - Working

http://localhost:4200/Products - Working (Page not found is getting rendered)

But when i access below url manually, i am getting blank page

http://localhost:4200/Product/1 -- Blank page

http://localhost:4200/Product/add -- Blank page

My expectation is it should redirect to Page not found component...What is the issue in the configuration

Note:

For simplicity i removed canActivate and canDeactivate properties

Comment: try : { path: '', component: ProducListComponent, pathMatch: 'full'},

Comment: Check the console for errors when you've got a blank page

Comment: Add `<router-outlet >` to `product component` too.

Comment: I would highly recommend using `routeProvider` with `routeProvider.when` for know routes and `routeProvider.otherwise` to handle unknown cases https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider

Comment: @David, in console i am getting the following:
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) for all JS files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve this...

Modified

`<base href="./">`

to

`<base href="/">`

It is working....Thanks for your support